# Resize a Layer Without Transform Controls

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, resize, transform

I would like to resize my layer without having to click the Transform Controls (the resize handles on the corners)

When using the move tool, once you do click the transform control, you can resize and reposition the layer by typing in values into X, Y, Width, and Height in toolbar.

How can I access that resize toolbar without having to click the transform controls? For example if the handles are way off-screen

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for here. Cmd/T is Transform [presumably Ctrl/T Win] then click in any of the numeric boxes [tab doesn't work at this point because it changes view] but once clicked you can then tab round the values & type new ones.

Comment: Thank you, Ctrl+T accomplishes what I need